# Multiselect only renders the first two items

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I want to use the multi select component and put this into a single file component

```
<template>
  <v-select
    :items="maskItem.values"
    item-text="display"
    item-value="value"
    :label="maskItem.fieldTitle"
    multiple
    chips
    return-object
    @input="onSelectedItemsUpdated"
  ></v-select>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: {
    maskItem: {
      type: Object,
      required: true
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onSelectedItemsUpdated: function(newItems) {
      this.$emit("selectedItemsUpdated", newItems);
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

This component should render a specific amount of items and fire an event with all the updated values. When I pass in these values

```
values: [
          {
            display: "Read",
            value: true
          },
          {
            display: "Write",
            value: false
          },
          {
            display: "Delete",
            value: false
          }
        ]
```

**only** the first two items are rendered. So I can place "Delete" before "Read" and "Write" will not get rendered.

I created an example to reproduce the problem

https://codesandbox.io/s/multiselect-hzu3z

Comment: this is weird i'm trying to find out why it is showing only first two `values` ... i consoled the values array on the method `onSelectedItemsUpdated` and got the 3 of them but only two are rendered hmm

Comment: If you make the value in values unique it renders all three

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you have duplicate `value` in two objects (i.e. "Write" and "Delete" have `false` `value`).

Make `value`s unique (arbitrary values, as long as they are unique):

```
values: [
  {
    display: "Read",
    value: 1
  },
  {
    display: "Write",
    value: 2
  },
  {
    display: "Delete",
    value: 3
  }
]
```

---

Note that native select also behaves like that:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/YoLxVr

Answer (score 0):

If you change the way your data is passed it will render:

```
return {
  maskItem: {
    items:["Read","Write","Delete"],
    values: [
      "Read"
    ],
    fieldTitle: "User permissions"
  }
};
```

Multiselect component:

```
<template>
  <v-select
    :items="maskItem.items"
    v-model="maskItem.values"
```

[Codepen](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiselect-h709b)

Comment: @SirDad nothing that I can see, vuetify doc doesn't seem to have an example of the syntax, and so until the syntax is figured out I believe this method works

Answer (score 0):

Got it , `item-value` is actually the reason why you are only seeing 2 items... i tried giving all of them `true` as a value and only one is rendered this time ... so `item-value` is rendering only one element for each value you have (in your case you have `true` and `false` values so you will get the first two items that will have these values)

==> you can fix this by giving values different value since you'r not using `v-model`for data binding :

```
values: [
      {
        display: "Delete",
        value: 'true1'
      },
      {
        display: "Read",
        value: 'false1'
      },
      {
        display: "Write",
        value: 'true2'
      }
    ]
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/multiselect-ozo1o)